# Snapchat browser: scrolling up closes my web page

Tags: reactjs, snapchat

I developed a website with React, when I access it on snapchat embedded web browser, a scroll up closes the web page. I saw other websites where the scroll up works.

How to prevent the snapchat browser to detect my scroll up when I scroll in my page?

Thanks